# Why october cms don't save attachments on db by upload images with amazon-s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a problem with AWS s3 and October cms.
If I upload images or files from media page s3 works fine, but if I upload images from Object (System or Widget) is attachment_id, and attachment_type on the system_file table is empty.
So, I cant fetch all images by model.

Someone have any idea whether it is an October cms error or I still have something to configure?

**filesystem.php config:**

```
'default' => 's3',
'cloud' => 's3',
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app'),
    ],
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('AWS3_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS3_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS3_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS3_BUCKET'),
    ],
```

**cms.php config:**

```
'storage' => [
    'uploads' => [
        'disk'   => 's3',
        'folder' => 'chemie/uploaded-files',
        'path'   => 'https://amazon/s3/bucket-name/chemie',
    ],
    'media' => [
        'disk'   => 's3',
        'folder' => 'chemie',
        'path'   => 'https://amazon/s3/bucket-name/chemie',
    ],
],
```

**sistem_file db table:**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMUdR.png)

**Model example:**

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
public $attachMany = [
    'gallery_images' => [
        'System\Models\File',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its not possible as `widget/file uploader` etc make relation to files and save that relation in database.

where as in media that is just plain path either of `local-disk` or `remote-disk` based on configuration

> So, if you want to add images which are stored on `s3` you can `add repeater field which have media widget in it to select files and upload files` in this way you can select or add multiple files.

as from code I see there is no possible implementation for `remote-disk` in database `FileSystem`

> Media uses remote disk

[image]

> File-upload widget/Model uses only local disk

[image]

if you have any doubts please comment.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

That means a solution would be to create an S3 file upload class or function yourself. I wonder if you can create something similar like "System \ Models \ File" and use it globally.

I think it is impractical not to use the table, and for each picture nen own field in each table to create and extra functions to write for it.

Comment: yes, you can create your own table and extend `System\Models\File` in new table you need to store `path` of `s3` items instead local one and you are good to go